# Redirecting URLs using htaccess & PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I would like all the URLs of the following format:

```
mysite.com/xyz
```

to display:

```
mysite.com/show.php?keyword=xyz
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work if you put this in .htaccess (given that mod_rewrite has been enabled on your webserver and you have the right to use it):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/xyz$ /show.php?keyword=xyz [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Err, I meant xyz as a variable, not literally "xyz". Does this work for a that?

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it just a regular expression?

Comment: Would `RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]*)$ /show.php?keyword=$1 [R=302,L]` work?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, you should just care that you don't create a loop. If the catching part also matches show.php you will be bricked.